# Why can't I reset my security token?

Tags: api, security-token

I need to get the Security Token so I can test an integration in with Salesforce, but I can't see the "Reset My Security Token" in my profile settings.

I am using the default System Administrator profile which has the "API Enabled" checkbox set to TRUE. Email deliverability is turned on also.

Is there any other settings I'm missing? This is in production, the option is available in the related sandbox.

Comment: See the article here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331668&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Please change into answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there are Login IP ranges enabled for your profile. Remove/delete them-->Reset your security token-->create Login IP Ranges again .

To check the range of IPs enabled::
Go to Profile-->Profile Overview-->Login IP Ranges.